# Is RosAsm assembler self-hosting?

Tags: assembly

I have a few questions about the RosAsm assembler (not in active development anymore) by René Tournois:

1. Is/was there a command-line tool (i.e. without a GUI) included to generate executable programs from assembly source? I'm a bit confused, because there are many random, suspiciously named .exe files in the release, and none of them seem to be the command-line tool.
2. Has the full source code of RosAsm been released?
3. Is RosAsm self-hosting, i.e. is it able to compile itself? (Is it possible to run this compilation from the Windows command-line?)

Download locations:

- [RosAsm home page on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20061123112434/http://betov.free.fr/)
- [RosAsm version 2093c binaries and source code on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20061123112541/http://betov.free.fr/RosAsmFull.zip). Extract the downloaded *RosAsmFull.zip* file, and find the source code in the file *RosAsm2093c.exe*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. As far as I’m aware, no.
2. Yes, [RosAsm](https://web.archive.org/web/20061123112434/http://betov.free.fr/) is GPL-licensed free software, and its source code is included inside the executables. (Run `strings RosAsm2049a.EXE` to see it.)
3. Yes, but not from the command-line as far as I know (see 1).